# i want to create simple login system. when i want to signup it show this

Tags: php

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

my signup.inc.php file is-

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
     include_once 'db.inc.php';

     $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
     $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
     $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
     $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
     $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

     //error handler
     //check for empty field

     if(empty($first) || empty($last)|| empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd))
     {
         header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
         exit();
     }
     else
     {
        //check if the input chcaracetr is vallied
            if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last))
            {
                 header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invallied");
                 exit();
            }
            else{
                //check if emial is vallied
                 if(!filter_var($email,filter_validate_email))
                 {
                      header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invallied email");
                      exit();
                 }else
                 {
                     $sql = "select * from users where user_uid= '$uid'";
                     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                     $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                     if($resultCheck > 0)
                     {
                         header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=user taken");
                         exit();
                     }
                     else{
                         //hashing the password
                         $hashpwd = password_hash($pwd , password_default);
                         //insert the user in the database
                         $sql = "insert into users (user_first,user_last,user_email,user_uid,user_pwd) values ('$first', '$last' ,  '$email' , '$uid' , '$pwd')";
                         //$result = 
                         mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

                         header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                         exit();
                     }
                 }
            }               
     }


 }else
 {
     header("Location: ../signup.php");
     exit();
 }
 ?>
```

my signup.php file is -

```
<?php

   include_once 'header.php';

?>
<section class="main-container">
     <div class="main-wrapper">
         <h2>Signup</h2>
         <form class="signup-form" action="include/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
             <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="Firstname">
             <input type="text" name="last" placeholder="Lastname">
             <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
             <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username">
             <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
             <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
         </form>
     </div>
</section>

<?php

   include_once 'footer.php';

?>
```

my header.php file is -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title> </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<header>
       <nav>
            <div class = "main-wrapper">
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                 </ul>
                 <div class = "nav-login">
                    <form>
                         <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/e-mail" 
                         >
                         <input type="text" name="ped" placeholder="Password">
                         <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
                    </form>
                    <a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
       </nav>
</header>
```

my footer.php file is -

```
</body>
</html>
```

i dont know but is it the problem cause when i install xampp this file (C:/XAMPP/htdocs/index.php) shows every time even i disable UAC(user account control) disable antivirus

[this is the index.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkW9Z.png)

Comment: Can you post your `signup.php` code?

Comment: @GonzaloPani this is a 404, it doesn't matter what's in that file if it's not found. A better thing to ask would be *where* `signup.php` is and then correct the `Location` headers appropriately.

Comment: Not downvoting, just stating - this seems like a very low-effort... "question".

Answer (score 0):

Set the location to the complete URL of the file.php, not just the filename

```
header("Location: http://website.com/signup.php");
```

Comment: You can drop the host, FWIW, so `/signup.php` would be ok too.

Comment: Yes but some older clients require an absolute URI including the scheme, hostname and absolute path. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself:

Comment: i set the location with complete url -  Location:C:\xampp\htdocs\loginSystem\signup.php  but it also seems same error !!!!!